Normal map baking issue - strange result
I wanted to bake normal map using selected to active, but apparently I'm doing something wrong.... Top hp mesh, middle lp, bottom lp with "normal map".

Edit: as @Jakemoyo mentioned in the comment, very small size of the UV island may be the reason, because it is tiny plug, and I baked all the model objects on one map. However, I decided to do another "test", this time with the default cylinder. I duplicated it, made these simple inward details:

and again I am not able to bake a correct normal map using selected to active.


You'll have to elaborate on your problem: what were the exact steps you took to bake the normal map, what does the normal map look like, can we see your UV map?

It looks like either your UVs are extremely small or your baking to a 28x28 pixel image. You need more resolution or you're never gonna get any detail.

In the example of your test cylinder, if the side faces of the inwardly extruded parts are perfectly perpendicular to the surface of the low poly cylinder then the rays cast out from the low poly cylinder will have nothing to detect so will result in a blank normal map. Try selecting the some of the horizontal edge loops of the high poly model and give them a little bevel then re-bake and you should then get a more interesting normal map.
